# Why is boost::optional<T> not convertable to bool for the purposes of std::is_convertible

Tags: c++, boost-optional

I have

```
auto result = std::is_convertible
    < boost::optional<int>
    , bool
    >::value;

static_assert( result , "task should return bool" );
```

and it fails to compile. The definition of [std::is_convertible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) is

```
template< class From, class To > struct is_convertible;
```

and optional is clearly convertible to boolean because we always use it like

```
void(boost::optional<int> const & value){
    if(value){
        std::cerr << *value << endl; 
    }
}
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`boost::optional`'s `operator bool` is `explicit`. It works inside an `if`'s condition, because it is a [contextual conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions).

You need [`std::is_constructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible), which tries to perform an explicit conversion.

The following compiles

```
static_assert
    ( std::is_constructible<bool, boost::optional<int>>::value
    , "msg" );
```

and the following fails to compile because optional is not convertible to int

```
static_assert
    ( std::is_constructible<int, boost::optional<int>>::value
    , "msg" );
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to use std::is_constructible to detect if I can convert the type to bool? I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing There's a gotcha in that the arguments are reversed compared to `std::is_convertible`, but it should be as simple as `std::is_constructible<bool, boost::optional<int>>`.

Comment: Thanks @quentin I added the examples to the answer so it's clear to the next person coming this way :)